# Lower possible screen resolution on MX Linux than Windows

Tags: display, resolution, mx-linux

I'm running MX Linux and Windows on the same machine. I'm using an LCD television screen connected via HDMI to the graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER).

**My problem:**

- On Windows, I can select resolutions way higher than 1024x768 (i.e. 1920x1080 and above).
- However, on MX Linux, 1024x768 is the highest resolution (800x600 and 640x480 are also selectable).
- Display settings in MX Linux only show one screen labelled "default".

**I tried:**

- using xrandr as [described here](https://gist.github.com/debloper/2793261).

  - "xrandr --newmode (...)" gives the error(/warning?): "Failed to get size of gamma for output default".
  - "xrandr --addmode default "1920x1080_60.00"" also gives "Failed to get size of gamma for output default".
  - "xrandr --output default --mode "1920x1080_60.00"" gives the **additional** message: "Configure crtc 0 failed".
  - no change in display happened after that.
- using arandr (GUI) *after* typing the above commands:

  - "default" is shown as screen
  - right-click --> resolution: shows the 3 resolutions mentioned above, *and also* "1920x108060.00"
  - selecting "1920x108060.00" and hitting the check sign --> pop-up error message: "(...) error code 1: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default" and "xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed".
  - no change in display happened after that.

I would appreciate any help. It is kind of inconvient having to work with this low (and stretched!) resolution on a 42'' LCD TV screen ;)

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 aka. [NV166](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/#nv160familyturing) is very new. The Debian-supplied driver "nouveau" does not really support it, yet as can be inferred from the [Feature Matrix](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix/).

You need to install the drivers for your graphics card. I strongly recommend using a package supplied by your distribution – **not** the installer from nvidia.com. The [package list](http://mxrepo.com/MX19packages.html) suggests, there is a pre-built package `nvidia-driver` in MX Linux. It looks like you need version 418 or newer.